# Вместо маркера загружается второе окно ,,найти,,

Tags: javascript

Подскажите  где ошибка в коде - строка`var SearchControl = new ymaps.control.SearchControl({Placemark:true});`должна выводить маркер на карту, а выводит второе окно ,,Найти,, Кто может подправте пожалуйста.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myMap, myPlacemark, adr, coords;
var index;

<?
if($_GET['adr'])
echo "\n adr='".urldecode($_GET['adr'])."';";
else
echo "\n adr='Moscow';";
?>


// Как только будет загружен API и готов DOM, выполняем инициализацию
    ymaps.ready(init);

    function init () {
        // Поиск координат центра 
        ymaps.geocode(adr, { results: 1 }).then(function (res) {
            // Выбираем первый результат геокодирования
            var firstGeoObject = res.geoObjects.get(0);

            // Создаём карту.
            // Устанавливаем центр и коэффициент масштабирования.
            window.myMap = new ymaps.Map("YMapsID", {
                center: firstGeoObject.geometry.getCoordinates(),
                zoom: 13
            });


        var SearchControl = new ymaps.control.SearchControl({yesPlacemark:true});   
        //Добавляем элементы управления 
        myMap.controls
            .add(SearchControl)                
        // Кнопка изменения масштаба
        .add('zoomControl')
        // Список типов карты
        .add('typeSelector'); 

        coords=firstGeoObject.geometry.getCoordinates();
        document.getElementById("spot-lat").value = coords[0].toFixed(4);   
        document.getElementById("spot-longi").value = coords[1].toFixed(4); 



        //Отслеживаем событие перемещения метки
        myPlacemark.events.add("dragend", function (e) {            
            coords = this.geometry.getCoordinates();
            savecoordinats();
        }, myPlacemark);


        //Отслеживаем событие выбора результата поиска
        SearchControl.events.add("resultselect", function (e) {
            index=SearchControl.getSelectedIndex();
            coords = SearchControl.getResultsArray()[index].geometry.getCoordinates();
            savecoordinats();
            //control.SearchControl.close();
        });


        }, function (err) {
            // Если геокодирование не удалось,
            // сообщаем об ошибке
            alert(err.message);
        })


 }


function savecoordinats (){ 
    var new_coords = [coords[0].toFixed(4), coords[1].toFixed(4)];  
    myPlacemark.getOverlay().getData().geometry.setCoordinates(new_coords);

    var center = myMap.getCenter();
    var new_center = [center[0].toFixed(4), center[1].toFixed(4)];  

    var new_center_x = [coords[0].toFixed(4)];  
    var new_center_y = [coords[1].toFixed(4)];  
    document.getElementById("spot-lat").value = new_center_x;   
    document.getElementById("spot-longi").value = new_center_y; 
}

function save_address() {
    var x = document.getElementById('spot-lat').value; 
    var y = document.getElementById('spot-longi').value; 
    window.opener.document.getElementById('map_x').value = x; 
    window.opener.document.getElementById('map_y').value = y; 
    self.close ();
}



</script>`
```

Comment: Я  нашел и исправил ошибку за строкой \ var SearchControl = new ymaps.control.SearchControl({Placemark:true}) \ правильно писать - \ myMaps.control \

Comment: Сейчас выходить такая ошибка - \ Неперехваченная ошибка ссылки: инициализация не определена на выполнение \ код - https://ideone.com/SEArnc

Указывает на эту строку - \ window.opener.document.getElementById('map_x').value = x; \ № 86

Comment: Все, тема закрыта - разобрался во всем и сделал.